# How can I make autocomplete feature using angularJs without using Jquery at all?

Tags: angularjs

I am making a tag field in form and I want to make this field autocomplete so that it shows suggestions from my $scope variable i.e local source.

```
<tags-input ng-model="tModel.tags"></tags-input>
```

But since my project `does not use jquery` `I cannot use the jquery autocomplete feature`.is there any way to make autocomplete using angularJs.

PS: i have searched many answers in stackoverflow but none worked for me.

Comment: You can use the HTML datalist tag

Comment: Did you checkout this directive ? https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic [**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/wkOqWBx3914sZk8AUirf?p=preview) on how to implement ui-bootstrap typeahead.I have used async call to fetch type ahead results from function `cities($viewValue)` instead you can just pass a list object here.

Your HTML will look like this with following scripts

```
<html>

  <head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
      <pre>Model: {{result | json}}</pre>
      <input type="text" ng-model="result" class="form-control" uib-typeahead="address for address in cities($viewValue)" />

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Your JS controller will have below code.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.factory('dataProviderService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var factory = {};
    factory.getCities = function(input) {

      return  $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
            params: {
                address: input,
                sensor: false
            }
        });

    };

    return factory;
}]);

app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', ['$scope', '$log','$http', 'dataProviderService', function($scope, $log,$http, dataProviderService) {
    $scope.cities = function(viewValue) {

     return   dataProviderService.getCities(viewValue).then(function(response) {
            return response.data.results.map(function(item) {
                return item.formatted_address;
            });
        });

    };


}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Angular [UI Bootstrap Typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) directive.

Comment: i am doing this....................

`<input type="text" ng-model="services" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"></tags-input>`

Comment: @lakshay you should use uib-typeahead instead of typeahead. I guess you are using the latest version of the library.

Comment: @lakshay have you added ui-bootstrap as a dependency to your app? angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

Comment: whenever i am adding this............i am getting an error. My module canot be instantiated.

Comment: Then that means you don't have the ui-bootstrap JavaScript included in your project.

Comment: how can i add that.

Comment: @lakshay just follow some of the installation guides http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn